# Did most Jedi Knights go on to become Masters?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Did most Jedi Knights eventually become Jedi Masters or did only a small fraction attain that rank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the [The Jedi Path : A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_%28real-life_book%29).

> The rank of Jedi Master is the highest formal recognition one can
>   achieve in the Jedi Order. It is not a requirement, nor does it mark
>   the end of your journey. **Jedi who have attained this rank are the
>   fewest in membership, and are outnumbered by even the younglings.**

Although this book is no longer considered canon (after the April Purge), it was written from an in-universe perspective by respected Star Wars author Daniel Wallace and with the assistance of LucasFilm's own people.

Comment: "and are outnumbered by even the younglings" - that seems like VERY MUCH like non-evidence to me - if you have 101 younglings, 100 of whom become Knights, and 99 of whom become Masters, 100% of that entire quote still applies and is true.

Comment: @DVK - Unless there was a dramatic influx of younglings, it would be astonishingly unlikely that there would be a matching number of younglings to knights. Assuming you remain a youngling for 13 years, you'd expect (in a normal distribution) to find that they represented 1/13th of the population.

Comment: Richard - Wouldn't that **heavily** depend on average lifespan of a Jedi Master? if it's 13 years or less, they would have same share as younglings (sans attrition of those who never rose to Master-y). If it's 130 years, it'd be 1:9 as you said.

Comment: @DVK - Again, purely based on the films and novels, the life of the average Jedi was relatively sedate until the War happened. Even the most active of them were basically policemen

Comment: not sure... Obi-Wan's earlier life certainly seemed dangerous way before Clone Wars.Never mind Old Republic and its wars.

Comment: @DVK - Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon are abnormal. They're the ones that get sent into the hairiest situations

Comment: I would have expected Tyvokka to be sent to the hairiest situations

Answer (score 1):

According to the [**Jedi Master**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Master) article on Wookieepedia:

> The rank of Master was a title bestowed upon very few Knights in every
>   generation. As such, Masters made up the smallest percent of the
>   Order's membership.

Unfortunately, it would be difficult to make a more informed comparison without having access to actual census data from the Jedi Order. Based on the various depictions in media, however, it would seem that Jedi Knights far outnumber Jedi Masters by at least 10 to 1.

Comment: The problem with the wiki is that anyone can write anything about anything

Comment: Not to say the title has to be given, Jedi have been know to assume the title by themselves.

Comment: @IG_42 You can do that? I guess I'm a Jedi Master now.

Comment: @IG_42 - can you cite that? The only one I'm aware of is Luke, and admittedly it's not like he had anyone around to promote him. Ulic Qel-Droma was given the title post-humously, but never assumed it for himself while alive.

Comment: Sorry, -1. Wookiepedia isn't canon and that particular statement isn't cited.

Comment: @DVK why, you little @^&^ *&(*)%$# $#@$%!$%!!!... fine. At least you said why and it's a legitimate reason.

Comment: @Omegacron - I downvoted Richard too if it makes it any better :)  I'm an equal opportunity hater on this question :)

Comment: @Omegacron To quote the Imperial Palace archives directly from Dark Force Rising in reference to one Jorus C'Baoth "Officially Assumed Title of Jedi Master 4.3.74 PE"(PE = Pre Empire Date)

Comment: "I don't like your source" is a bad reason to downvote on its own.  I don't see anyone providing any evidence that this isn't *correct*.