# What did Anakin need to do in order to become a Master Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Before Mace Windu goes to see Palpatine in *Revenge of the Sith* he tells Anakin that, if what Anakin says about Palpatine being a Sith Lord is true, he will have gained his trust.

Was Mace's mistrust the reason that he wasn't becoming a master?  What else did Anakin need to do in order to become a Master Jedi?

Comment: There are really two questions here. 1) How could Anakin become a master? 2) Why did Windu not trust Anakin? The first is touched upon [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84582/did-most-jedi-knights-go-on-to-become-masters). Not every Jedi becomes a master. It's not necessarily anything personal. There are trials to be undertaken.

Comment: I see.  I guess I was assuming his distrust of Anakin was related to him not becoming a Master.

Comment: The fact that we've got two answers focused on separate questions here is proof that this is too broad.

Comment: @phantom42 just to be thorough, I added a final paragraph to my answer that addresses the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, Mace Windu - and many other Jedi Masters - did NOT trust Anakin Skywalker. There had always been a darkness about him, ever since he was first introduced as a child. Beyond that, he often proved to be reckless, headstrong, and ambitious - all attributes the Jedi attempted to avoid. In fact, they were typically the attributes of the Sith. This was first hinted at when young Anakin was being evaluated by the Jedi Council:

> **YODA:** Afraid are you?
>
> **ANAKIN:** No, sir.
>
> **YODA:** See through you, we can.
>
> **MACE WINDU:** Be mindful of your feelings...
>
> **KI-ADI:** Your thoughts dwell on your mother.
>
> **ANAKIN:** I miss her.
>
> **YODA:** Afraid to lose her... I think, hmm?
>
> **ANAKIN:** (a little angry) What's that got to do with anything?
>
> **YODA:** Everything. Fear is the path to the dark side... fear leads to
>   anger... anger leads to hate.. hate leads to suffering... *I sense much
>   fear in you*.

Yoda mentions it again when informing Kenobi of the Council's decision:

> **YODA:** Confer on you, the level of Jedi Knight the Council does. But
>   agree on you taking this boy as your Padawan learner, I do not.
>
> **OBI-WAN:** Qui-Gon believed in him.
>
> **YODA:** The Chosen One the boy may be; nevertheless, *grave danger I fear
>   in his training*.
>
> **OBI-WAN:** Master Yoda, I gave Qui-Gon my word. I will train Anakin.
>   Without the approval of the Council if I must.

Both Mace and Yoda had often discussed both the potential and danger of Anakin Skywalker, yet both trusted Obi-Wan Kenobi implicitly. It was their hope that Kenobi's teachings would "smooth out" the rough spots in Anakin and eventually help him become true to the Jedi Way.

Much of this disagreement about Anakin takes place off-screen, so this statement serves two purposes - A) it sums up the mistrust of Anakin in a single sentence, but also B) shows that Anakin can still be redeemed at this point.

> **MACE WINDU:** Then our worst fears have been realized. We must move
>   quickly if the Jedi Order is to survive.
>
> **ANAKIN:** Master, the Chancellor is very powerful. You will need my help
>   if you are going to arrest him.
>
> **MACE WINDU:** For your own good, stay out of this affair. I sense a
>   great deal of confusion in you, young Skywalker. *There is much fear
>   that clouds your judgment*.
>
> **ANAKIN:** I *must* go, Master.
>
> **MACE WINDU:** No. If what you told me is true, you will have gained my
>   trust, but for now remain here.

The title of Jedi Master is given to a Jedi Knight to show that they have an advanced understanding of the Jedi Way & The Force. In essence, a Jedi Master should embody the traits and ideals upheld by the Jedi Order. In the minds of many Masters, this is something that Anakin hadn't even come close to yet. To achieve the title, he would not only need to change his attitude considerably, but also pass the trials like any other Jedi Knight.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood in the movies, the general disagreement was that whilst Anakin was powerful enough in the force to become a Jedi Master, he had not fully embraced the way that the Jedi Order operated.

He was very ambitious and impatient to become a Jedi Master, because he knew that he possessed the power, however this very reason for wanting to become a Jedi Master flew in the face of the Jedi teachings.

As stated in the linked answer, the Jedi Masters were few and far between, and being heads of the Jedi Order they needed to be the absolute embodiment of the Jedi teachings, in order to be able to represent the Jedi Order to the rest of the galaxy.

Perhaps the other Masters felt that he was not ready to accept this responsibility, and therefore would not make him a Jedi Master until he embraced the philosophies of patience and understanding.

However, when Anakin told Mace Windu that his own close friend, Palpatine, was a Sith Lord, I'm guessing Windu figured that Anakin was accepting to embrace the Jedi code rather than the Sith, otherwise he would have joined Palpatine there and then.

Of course, there is always the out-of-universe answer that Windu said that to make sure the audience believed that the reason Anakin killed Mace Windu was because he was going to assassinate Palpatine, rather than for his own ambition and disagreement of Mace for preventing becoming a Jedi Master.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, you ask two distinct questions.

Mike answered the first one very well.

The second question, why didn't Mace Windu trust Anakin about Palpatine?

This isn't matter of trust. The Jedi have always been cautious about new information. Even Master Yoda was *questioned* by Mace as well regarding the Sith controlling the senate. I don't think Mace distrusted Anakin at all, but rather took the information as one single source that needs to be further investigated before action is taken.